# CSS masonry with ordering

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, masonry

I have a problem regarding positioning, ordering and breaking divs for mobile.

[image]
Above is a simplified image of a layout I currently have. The issue is with the whitespace above **description** section which happens due to higher **main** section.

I'd like for it to go up and fill empty space.

Also, I need to break it into mobile view like this (each 100% width):

Main
Gallery
Description
Amenities

This I can achieve with flexbox, or lost grid, or any other ordering, but then I can't get rid of whitespace.

I've tried flexbox positioning, float positioning, lost-column positioning, css3 columns, but I'm now out of ideas.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fxfnr6y/4/) for Flexbox example which doesn't solve the issue but shows the problem and general idea.

In example:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: CSS columns can do something like that https://jsfiddle.net/1fxfnr6y/5/

Comment: And using a fixed height, it can be done using Flexbox columns https://jsfiddle.net/1fxfnr6y/6/

Comment: Content has dynamic height so it's not an option. Columns look like what I was looking for, but I'm not sure they are able to break as needed, since I need source ordering as well @LGSon

Comment: The dupe link has more options

Comment: @LGSon None of the solutions are what I'm looking for. Columns do it top-to-bottom first, which breaks the ordering which is needed for responsive breaks, others don't handle whitespace well.